# Jenkins: trigger build when changes occur to one branch, but fire script in another branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins Pipeline Job that triggers when changes are pushed to a Git repository:

```
pipelineJob('MyJob') {
    definition {
        cpsScm {
            scm {
                git {
                    remote {
                        url('git@bitbucket.org:myorg/myproject.git')
                        credentials('jenkins-bitbucket')
                    }
                    branch('develop')
                    branch('master')
                    branch('release/*')
                    branch('hotfix/*')
                }
            }
        }
    }
    properties {
        triggers{
            bitbucketTriggers {
                repositoryPushAction(false,false,'develop')
            }
        }
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
}
```

When the job triggers, I want to run a groovy script located in *a different* Git repository. Is that possible?

Comment: It seems unlikely that a Jenkins job could be set up that uses the script from a different git repository than it is triggered by. Do you keep your Jenkinsfiles in a single repository across all projects? Maybe you could include the Jenkinsfile repo as a submodule of the source repo, and use [submodule options](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-definition-cpsScm-scm-git-extensions-submoduleOptions) and [scm scriptPath](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-definition-cpsScm-scriptPath) to define it?

Comment: You could do a git checkout of the other repository and then use the load step to execute the script

Answer (score 0):

> 

Yes there are two solutions,

1. Shared Libraries - [url](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)
2. This approach is more customized. You can create you own Java library and export as customlib.jar file. Ensure Java classpath appends the customlib.jar file you created. Then you can access the code directly in your JenkinsFile like import customlib.classname.*

Good luck!